# Try to getting score value based from input but fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Before asking this, I already try to successfully grab the score value

Here is my script

```js
<script>   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://example.com/paylist.php?acc=useraccount&json=1",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#total').text(data.pending[0].pending);
        }
     });
</script>
```

It grabs successfully the `data.pending[0].pending`
and I want to make an input box to let my blog visitor get score of their own account, but it failed

I changed my script to

```js
<script>  
function onClaim(token) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://example.com/paylist.php? 
                       acc='+useraccount+'&json=1",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#total').text(data.pending[0].pending);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my input box and search button

```html
<div> 
<input required="" type="text" style="width: 90%; max-width: 600px; text-   align: center;" name="useraccount" id="useraccount" placeholder="Your account"    value=""> 
</div> 
<div> 
<button style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"    id="findbutton"  data-callback="onClaim">Find</button> 
</div> 
<center><a  style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102);">score: </a><span id="total"  style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102);"></span></center>
```

I didnt get any error message when I try running it.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: why the `>` next the `>acc` param

Answer (score 0):

first get the useraccount value  `var useraccount = $("#useraccount").val();`

then your AJAX URL should be as below :

```
url: "https://example.com/paylist.php?acc="+useraccount+"&json=1",
```

Comment: the '>' on my code just typo when i try to post it on this site, sorry for my mistake

Comment: Please replace the last html line with: <center><a  style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102);">score: </a><span id="total"  style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102);"></span></center>

Comment: thanks for advise @bRIMOs , i already try that and it wont work either

Comment: If you try with the hardocoded `https://example.com/paylist.php?acc=useraccount&json=1" ` does it work ??

Comment: and already try with 
var useraccount = $("#useraccount").val().toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\_]/g, '');
wont work either

Comment: nothing show in console... thats why i am confused @bRIMOs

Comment: try echo GET['acc'] from back end ! what does it show in the page ?